# Relation between basis and Similar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I don't understand how it is true. In my book there is a lemma which says:

Characteristic polynomial , determinant and Trace of a linear transformation of finite dimensional vector space are independent of chosen **basis**.

I understand that similar matrices have same characteristics polynomial,determinant and Trace but i don't understand how is it independent of chosen basis?

Comment: Actually writing out the argument for the trace with explicit bases is quite a nice exercise. After this, you can use that a change of basis is always $M \mapsto X M X^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $X$, and use properties of the trace and the determinant.

Comment: Two square matrices are similar if and only if they are the matrices of the same linear transformation with respect to different bases, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997256/meaning-of-similar-transformations/1997282#1997282).

Comment: @Luai Ghunim If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of basis is a similarity transformation.

Take also a look here for more details:

[Change of basis = similarity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82250/change-of-basis-similarity)

Comment: Thank you again @gimusi, I'm a noob in linear algebra

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad to can help you to get into the topic! Bye